# Which expression in the conversation below is not an utterance?

Tags: theoretical-linguistics

This is a question from an MA entrance exam. 'Too tasteless' is the correct choice. I'm wondering why it's the correct choice. In other words, Why 'Too tasteless' is not considered an utterance? Would it have been an utterance if the speaker A had said It's too tasteless?

Which expression in the conversation below is not an utterance?

Speaker A: I really like strawberry ice cream.
Speaker B: Me too. My second favorite flavor is vanilla.
Speaker A: I don't care for vanilla. Too tasteless, in my opinion.
Speaker B: Really? I think it has great taste.

1. Too tasteless. 2. I don't care for vanilla. 3. Me too. 4. Really?

Answer (score 3):

In [orthographic](https://www.thoughtco.com/utterance-speech-1692576#:%7E:text=In%20linguistics%2C%20an%20utterance%20is,sounds%20that%20constitute%20an%20utterance.) terms, an utterance is a syntactic unit that **begins with a capital letter** and **ends in a period, question mark, or exclamation point**.

So I bet "Too tasteless" in your example is followed by a comma, indicating that it is only a segment of a composite utterance. All the other 3 options fit the definition stated above.

Comment: I fear you are correct. In actuality, of course, whatever people utter is an utterance, and utterances don't have any punctuation because they're, ... um ... uttered. I would have second thoughts about getting any degrees from an institution with such stupid questions on its entrance exam.